# Removing an element from a list in the loop

Tags: python, list, loops, error-handling, element

```
import stdio
import sys
import random

SUITS = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
RANKS = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen ", "King", "Ace"]


rank = random . randrange (0 , len( RANKS ))
suit = random . randrange (0 , len( SUITS ))
stdio . writeln ( RANKS [ rank ] + "of" + SUITS [ suit ])

deck = []
for rank in RANKS :
    for suit in SUITS :
        card = rank + "of" + suit
        deck += [ card ]


n = len ( deck )
for i in range ( n ):
    r = random . randrange (i , n)
    temp = deck [r]
    deck [r] = deck [i]
    deck [i] = temp


h = []

b = int(sys.argv[1])

k = 1
for l in range(b):
    while k <= b:
        f = random.randrange(n)
        h += [deck[f]]
        deck.pop([deck[f]]) # this line is the problem, i wnat to move [deck[f]], from deck but getting a                      
                               type eror
        k += 1
    print(h)
```

### # this is my command prompt

File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\app\pokerhands.py", line 37, in 
    deck.pop([deck[f]])
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: You need to specify the index of the item to remove not the value.  Try: `deck.pop(f)'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `deck.pop([deck[f]])`, try `deck.pop(f)`.

`list.pop(index)` removes the element at `index`. You are trying to use a list containing a string as an index, rather than an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `del deck[f]` or use `deck.pop["index of element in deck"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow.

There are two things I noticed which you are doing.

#### Firstly

`.pop(arg)` is a built-in python function that takes an **index** as a parameter, not an array value.

So firstly change `deck.pop([deck[f]])` to be `deck.pop(f)`, assuming you want to randomly remove elements from the list inside your loop.

#### Secondly

Your are randomly selecting an index between (0, n) to remove from your list. However, on each iteration you are not reducing the value of `n` and therfore, could get an index array out of bounds exception. Simple fix is to just decrease the value of `n` on each iteration. Like so:

`n -= 1`